# Textbox width growing infinitely with text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Before explaining my problem here is my code:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" >
            <Grid Margin="0,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Name: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="parametro" Text="{Binding Username}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="Creation Date: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationDate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="Creation User: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="4" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationUser}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Foreground="Green" FontSize="13" Width="50" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Content="&#xf00c;" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Foreground="Red" FontSize="13" Width="50" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Content="&#xf00d;" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteUser}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=parametro, Path=Text}"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="combo" SelectedItem="{Binding Role}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                    Path=DataContext.Roles}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Ruolo: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Descrizione: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

My problem is that when I write text in the textbox (last element in the xaml), the width of the textbox grows with it. Now I know that there is a maxwidth property, but since I don't have a defined width for my grid columns, I can't bind it to the width of my textbox. I don't want to set the width in terms of real pixels, since I want my application to be "resizable". I also tried to create a fake control like a Border, and bind the width of the textbox to it but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to make the template assume the size of its parent.

1. Set TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" on the textbox.
2. At least one column must have a width of `*` rather than the default of `Auto`. This will cause the Grid to size itself to its parent. The second column seemed best to me for that role.
3. Give the Grid `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` so it doesn't end up getting centered.
4. You can get rid of the StackPanel; it's not doing anything for you.

Second, we need to make some changes in the DataGrid to constrain the width of its row details area.

This is my example I tested with; your ItemsSource will differ of course.

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    >
    <!-- 
    ScrollContentPresenter includes the row header column. 
    DataGridDetailsPresenter doesn't. So we set RowHeaderWidth="0"
    above to avoid making the details too wide by an amount equal to 
    the width of the row header. 

    This is just cosmetic, so leave RowHeaderWidth alone if you have 
    a requirement to keep the row header visible. 
    -->
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid 
                Margin="0,10" 
                Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Name: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="parametro" Text="{Binding Username}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="Creation Date: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationDate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="Creation User: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="4" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationUser}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Foreground="Green" FontSize="13" Width="50" Content="&#xf00c;" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Foreground="Red" FontSize="13" Width="50" Content="&#xf00d;" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"
                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteUser}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=parametro, Path=Text}"/>
                <ComboBox MaxWidth="185" x:Name="combo" SelectedItem="{Binding Role}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                Path=DataContext.Roles}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Ruolo: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Descrizione: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox 
                    Grid.Row="8" 
                    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    ></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

---

How did I figure this out?

I added preview mouse-down handler to the Grid in the DataTemplate:

```
<Grid Margin="0,10" Background="WhiteSmoke" PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown">
```

Ran my test program with some test data, clicked on a row to expand the row details, and clicked in the row details area. And this is the handler I have for that mouse event:

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    List<DependencyObject> parents = new List<DependencyObject>();
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as DependencyObject);
    while (parent != null)
    {
        parents.Add(parent);
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    ;
}
```

I set a breakpoint and looked at `parents` in the watch window.

```
-       parents Count = 16  System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.DependencyObject>
+       [0] {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridDetailsPresenter}   System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridDetailsPresenter}
+       [1] {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.SelectiveScrollingGrid} System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.SelectiveScrollingGrid}
+       [2] {System.Windows.Controls.Border}    System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Border}
+       [3] {System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow}   System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow}
+       [4] {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter}  System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter}
+       [5] {System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter}    System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter}
+       [6] {System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter}    System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter}
+       [7] {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}  System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}
+       [8] {System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer}  System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer}
+       [9] {System.Windows.Controls.Border}    System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Border}
+       [10]    {System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:10}   System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid}
+       [11]    {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}  System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}
+       [12]    {System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter}  System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter}
+       [13]    {System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator} System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator}
+       [14]    {System.Windows.Controls.Border}    System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Border}
+       [15]    {CS7Test02.MainWindow}  System.Windows.DependencyObject {CS7Test02.MainWindow}
```

The Grid's parent is `DataGridDetailsPresenter`:

```
+       [0] {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridDetailsPresenter}   System.Windows.DependencyObject {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridDetailsPresenter}
```

His parent is `SelectiveScrollingGrid`, and on up the chain. By simple trial and error, I found the parent with the `ActualWidth` I wanted, and bound to that.

I found another way of applying the desired width as a feature of the DataGrid itself rather than the datatemplate. This lets you use arbitrary details templates without having to individually fix up each one to use the correct width.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!-- 
    This style exists only so we can use its Resources to declare 
    the DataGridDetailsPresenter style someplace where it'll be taken
    as an implicit style for DataGridDetailsPresenter in this grid's 
    row details children.
    -->                
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridDetailsPresenter">
                <Setter 
                    Property="Width" 
                    Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" 
                    />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: The textbox width still grow with the text inside it, when this one exceed the dimension

Comment: @DanieleSartori Sorry, I made a mistake. It is required for at least one column to have a width of `*`.

Comment: the problem still remain

Comment: @DanieleSartori I tested the code I gave you. It should work -- the only possibility is that the context in which you are using it allows the grid control to grow arbitrarily. I would look at setting relative grid column sizes.

Comment: I am off from work now. Tomorrow i will update my post with more codes. However the datagrid that own this template is not affected

Comment: That was simply an awesome work. You save my day, and now i can move forward with my app. I used the first solution since i already worked with the style of the datagrid row.